# Unable to load native-hadoop library for IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, apache-spark

This is my simple Scala-Spark object created in IntelliJ IDE using [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html) project (part of the code was taken from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html)).

```
package test

import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Test {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("CountingSheep")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Load and parse the data file.
    val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/adalone.txt")
    // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
    val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
    val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

    // Train a RandomForest model.
    //  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
    val numClasses = 2
    val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
    val numTrees = 3 // Use more in practice.
    val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" // Let the algorithm choose.
    val impurity = "variance"
    val maxDepth = 4
    val maxBins = 32

    val model = RandomForest.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
      numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)

    // Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
    val labelsAndPredictions = testData.map { point =>
      val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
      (point.label, prediction)
    }
    val testMSE = labelsAndPredictions.map{ case(v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2)}.mean()
    println("Test Mean Squared Error = " + testMSE)
    println("Learned regression forest model:\n" + model.toDebugString)

    // Save and load model
    model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
    val sameModel = RandomForestModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
  }
}
```

The project was successfully compiled, however when I run it the following error appears (see below). It says `Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform`.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/11/25 12:04:44 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.1
15/11/25 12:04:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/network/shuffle/ShuffleClient : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:450)
    at test.Test$.<init>(Test.scala:13)
    at test.Test$.<clinit>(Test.scala)
    at test.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ben Watson: Ok, thanks, java issue is fixed. But now it says: java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

Comment: Chech that your HADOOP_HOME path varible points to the correct Hadoop folder (without \bin subdir)

Comment: @maxteneff: I did this. Now HADOOP_HOME appears in the list of System Variables (System->Advanced system settings/Environmental variables. Then I rebuilt the project and executed the Scala object. Again the same error: java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries

Comment: does the winutils.exe exists in HADOOP_HOME\bin\?

Comment: @maxteneff: The only reason that comes to my mind is that maybe my version of Hadoop is not ok. I just downloaded hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master and specified this folder/bin as a HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: @maxteneff: yes, please see my update. I putted the screenshot of the content of the folder. And then I have HADOOP_HOME: D:\SOFTWARE\BIGDATA\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master\bin

Comment: you say that your HADOOP_HOME is specified as folder/bin, but it shoud be without \bin subfolder. In your case: HADOOP_HOME=D:\SOFTWARE\BIGDATA\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master

Comment: @maxteneff: Ok, now it's without bin (see my update). I also rebuilt the project and got the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96153/discussion-between-maxteneff-and-klausos-klausos).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after adding the following line of code inside the main loop of my Scala object:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\SOFTWARE\\BIGDATA\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master\\")
```